# Can I limit the CPU usage of a single application?

Tags: performance, resource-limiting

Is there a way to stop ClamScan eating my server CPU?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just as an alternative to cpulimit:

You could start clamscan with the nice-command, e.g.

`nice -n 19 clamscan`.

See `man nice` for details.

It does **NOT** limit the CPU, but it does **lower the priority** of the process.

Also there is `renice` to alter the priority of running processes.

Comment: It looks like it still works eating a lot of cpu...

Comment: As long as no other process requires cputime, clamscan gets a lot of it. But as soon as another process (which has a higher priority) needs cputime, clamscan has no chance. cpulimit limits absolute cputime, and nice limits relative cputime.

Comment: +1. `nice`ing is the traditional way to go, and for good reason.

Comment: Are there any tools to define a default nice value for particular applications to run with? Preferably a tool that lets you compare all of your presets side-by-side.

Answer (score 23):

Install [cpulimit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cpulimit)

```
sudo apt-get install cpulimit
```

It provides different methods of limiting the CPU usage of a process `foo` to say, 20%

- By its process-name: 
  `sudo cpulimit -e foo -l 20`.
- By its absolute path name: 
  `sudo cpulimit -P /usr/bin/foo -l 20`
- By its PID:

  1. Find the PID of the process: `pidof foo`. (say, it outputs 1881)
  2. `sudo cpulimit -p 1881 -l 20`

Comment: No target process found...

Maybe it's because I have a script to run clamscan?

i do:

sudo cpulimit -e /etc/cron.hourly/virusscan -l 15

Comment: @Pitto: You have entered a wrong command, `/etc/cron.hourly/virusscan` is not a process. If you need to limit `clamscan`, run `sudo cpulimit -e clamscan -l 15`.

Comment: Oh! Right!
So I should start cpulimit at startup in rc.local, right?

Comment: `sudo` is not required the process isn't a system process. Just as a note

Comment: This would be a really neat solution if used programattically! Does it support pattern-based searches?

Answer (score 5):

If you're running clamd with systemd, you could use the [`CPUQuota`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#CPUQuota=) option.

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service` to include this line in the `[Service]` section:

```
CPUQuota=20%
```

Then restart the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl reload-or-restart clamav-daemon
```

Answer (score 4):

This was going to be a comment on Clausi's answer (which I believe is the most "correct" from a system administration viewpoint, in my opinion) but it bloomed into something too big to fit in the comment box.

- Clamscan has a fixed amount of work to do so limiting it to a certain speed means it's just going to take longer. It's going to hold the CPU in contention for longer.
- Allow it to run as fast as it can means you use your CPU to its fullest. Making it very "nice" means it'll let other processes do their work before its own. This means if there are lots of other busy processes, yes, it'll take a long time to do its own work but if there's nothing on there, it'll just chunk through its workload.

Answer (score 1):

This topic can be useful: [HOWTO: Set maximum CPU consumption in percentage by any process](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706)