# Crash at high CPU usage

Tags: hardware, 64-bit

My machine seems to die whenever the CPU does any large amount of work. This is like running a few programs and transferring files. I didn't have any issues with XP.

I didn't install any Mobo drivers, could that be a problem?? 
Any thoughts would help!

Hardware :

- CPU : AMD 3700+ ATHLON 64 939P RT 2.20 gigahertz
- Mobo : MSI K8NGM2-FID GF6150 939
- RAM : 2 x 512mb of DDR 400 ram
- Video Card : MSI N9500GT-MD512M
- HD : Maxtor 200gb SATA + WD Green 2TB SATA

**Updated** : When the machine does shut off, the power light does a slow blink. To turn it back on, I have turn the power supply off for a bit and/or pull the power cord out until the light turns off.

Comment: subtle title. :)

Comment: Might not get a meaningful answer with that title.

Comment: die meaning what? it shuts down? it overheats? it coughs, spits and collapses? what does it do?

Comment: It sounds like its overheating. Are your fans working?

Comment: have you tried to clean up your fans? dust can kill any machine regardless of the OS, also it can be failing hardware...

Comment: Indeed. My old desktop computer showed random strange behavior, and the day arrived when it would even hang after starting it up. I opened the case and blowed the dust out of it and carefully cleaned the fans. After doing that, the computer worked normally.

Comment: Hell I even had the dust issue with my old PlayStation 2. Brothers saw me as mr techy for fixing it and all I did was clean it up :P

Comment: Sounds like your system hibernates from your description.

Comment: I wonder if the power supply is being overtaxed and shutting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/) to see the temperatures. See [issue 43 of Full Circle Magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/issue-43/), the Q&A section.

Comment: I have a temperature readout on my case, it's not reporting anything crazy. But I'll install the Im-sensors tonight.

Comment: So, tracking the temp and tweeking it helped. Also the system is in a MicroATX case and the mobo was off it's tracks. I'm not sure which fixed it, but its working now!

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to throttle the CPU usage of a game for example, you can use cpulimit. See [Can I limit the CPU usage of a single application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21056/can-i-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-single-application) I had to do this with a game called Tibia which is a CPU hog on Ubuntu, its now limited to 50% CPU with cpulimit.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally - you can try installing CPULIMIT and control the beast's cpu consumption. I had this problem with my DELL N5010 & I couldn't do anything with the fan speed. Installed CPULIMIT and throttled the Video conversion utility. I am able to get things done without my Laptop crashing - though, the speed is compromised. Well - I guess it is about to be the case - and better than looking for a fan replacement (or whatever else).